# How to Integrate Oauth2 in Phalcon PHP

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, facebook-login, phalcon, google-signin

Please can anyone help me with an idea on how exactly i can integrate oauth2 login API to my phalcon php project so that a user can login with google and facebook, i have tried many examples i saw but haven't succeeded yet. Please can anyone show me a working example of Oauth2 in Phalcon php?

Comment: Have a look at here: https://phalcontip.com/discussion/51/phalcon-authentication-with-oauth and https://auth0.com/docs/

Comment: i used this months ago, it didn't work at the end, no error